# How to approach this proof problem, what proof to use, what assumption to use?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

This is a problem from Discrete Mathematics and its Applications
[image]

Here is the definition of rational that my book uses 
[image]

Usually when I approach this type of a problem, I can find a type of proof to use and what assumption to make. But for this one I can't find one that works

First I tired a direct proof. That is, I assumed $r$ is irrational or there do not exists integers $p$ and $q$ with $q\neq 0$ such that $r = \frac{p}{q}$. But I couldn't go from that to saying $|r - n| < \frac{1}{2}$ where $n$ is some integer.

I also tried proof by contradiction. The initial problem is proving $p \to q$ so proof by contradiction would be showing that $\neq (p\to q)$ or $p\land \neg q$ leads to a contradiction. I didn't know how to get from $r$ being a rational number to there not being an integer $n$ for which $|r - n| < 1/2$.

Lastly, I tried proof by contraposition, which would be $\neg q \to \neg p$. If there is not a unique integer $n$ such that the distance between $r$ and $n$ is less than $1/2, r$ is rational. But how would you get from for all integers $|r-n| \geq 1/2$ to $r$ is rational?

Comment: You're going about this in fundamentally the wrong way. The first step in proving something non-trivial isn't to systematically try various formal techniques, it's far more intuitive: the first step is to try to *convince yourself that it's obvious*. Only if this fails should you fall back on pure logic. In this case, since we're talking about distances between real numbers, a natural first step would be to draw a picture. Brian M. Scott's answer is of course the idea that immediately occurs to you when you try this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: If $x$ is irrational, then $x$ is not an integer, so there is a unique integer $n$ that $n<x<n+1$. Clearly the distance from $x$ to the closer of $n$ and $n+1$ is at most $\frac12$. If $x$ is irrational, can that distance be $\frac12$?

**Added:** Please take note also of **Jack M**’s excellent comment under the original question; I was a bit rushed when I wrote my answer, or I’d have tried to make the same point. Picking a proof technique first is usually a bad idea: the nature of the problem itself and any intuitions that you can form about it should guide the choice of proof technique to try.

Comment: Could you explain formally why the distance cannot equal a half? It makes sense but how would you say that mathematically?

Comment: @Gabriel: What’s the only number in that interval for which the distance *is* $\frac12$?

Comment: @Gabriel Suppose $n$ is an integer and $|x-n|=1/2$. So either $x-n=1/2$ or $n-x=1/2$ depending on the sign of $x-n$ (this is just using the definition of absolute value). Solve for $x$ in each case and conclude by taking a contrapositive and using the assumption that $x$ is irrational.

Comment: @Gabriel: Let me take an explicit example. Suppose that $n=1$; what’s the only number between $1$ and $2$ that is exactly $\frac12$ distant from $1$ (and $2$)? Is it rational, or irrational?

Comment: 3/2 rational. Because irrationals don't have a concrete decimal expansion?

Comment: @Gabriel: $\frac32$ is right, but you’re making the rest too hard: $\frac32$ is rational simply because it’s the quotient of two integers. It’s $p/q$ with $p=3$ and $q=2$. More generally, the only number between $n$ and $n+1$ that’s half a unit from either end is $n+\frac12$; can you write that as a quotient of integers? If you can, you’ve proved that it’s rational. Every irrational in the interval is then either between $n$ and $n+\frac12$ or between $n+\frac12$ and $n+1$, and from that the desired conclusion follows easily.

Answer (score 1):

For every real number $r$ except members of $\{\pm0.5, \pm1.5,\pm2.5,\pm3.5,\ldots\}$ there is a unique integer $n$ such that the distance between $r$ and $n$ is less than $1/2$.

If $r$ is irrational, then $r\not\in\{\pm0.5, \pm1.5,\pm2.5,\pm3.5,\ldots\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Given $r$, let $a$ be the closest integer to $r$ less than $r$, and let $b$ be the closest integer to $r$ greater than $r$. In the notation introduced in Section 1.8 [I also have this book], we have $a=\lfloor r \rfloor$ and $b=\lceil r \rceil$. In fact, $b=a+1$. The distance between $r$ and any integer other than $a$ or $b$ is greater than $1$ so cannot be less than $\frac{1}{2}$. Furthermore, since $r$ is irrational, it cannot be exactly half-way between $a$ and $b$, so exactly one of $r-a < \frac{1}{2}$ and $b-r < \frac{1}{2}$ holds.